# Pass GeckoFX DOM elements to JavaScript navigation calls

Tags: c#, javascript, dom, geckofx

using GeckoFX web browser, is it possible to pass a GeckoElement through JavaScript like this,

```
WebBrowser.Navigate("javascript:void("+ele.DomObject+".onclick())");
```

I'm selecting the DOM element through JavaScript (this works fine) atm, but i have the element in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately elements can't be passed to javascript like that.

However, the WebBrowser.Navigate call is unnecessary and causes an unneeded loss of page variables.

For the sake of completeness I've posted a snippet - long winded for this occasion ;) - that injects javascript and then calls it from an automated button click via a button.click() handler without the need to navigate the browser to run it all.

```
DOM.GeckoScriptElement script = Document.CreateElement("script").AsScriptElement();
script.Type = "text/javascript";
script.Text = "function doAlert(){ alert('My alert - fired by automating a button click on the [Automated Button]'); }";
Document.Body.AppendChild(script);

script = Document.CreateElement("script").AsScriptElement();
script.Type = "text/javascript";
script.Text = "function callDoAlert(id){ var el = document.getElementById(id); el.click(); }";
Document.Body.AppendChild(script);

DOM.GeckoInputElement button = Document.CreateElement("input").AsInputElement();
button.Type = "button";
button.Id = "myButton";
button.Value = "Automated Button";
button.SetAttribute("onclick", "javascript:doAlert();");

Document.Body.AppendChild(button);

DOM.GeckoInputElement button2 = Document.CreateElement("input").AsInputElement();
button2.Type = "button";
button2.Id = "myOtherButton";
button2.Value = "Press Me";
button2.SetAttribute("onclick", "javascript:document.getElementById('myButton').click();");

Document.Body.AppendChild(button2);

//uncomment to fully automate without the <webbrowser>.Navigate("javascript:.."); hack
//button2.click();
```

I'm not sure this snippet will help you, directly, as it's mainly focused on using the [GFXe](http://se7en-soft.com/GFXe/default.aspx) build of the control but, I'm sure it will point you in a better direction than the

WebBrowser.Navigate("javascript:hack.goesHere()"); trick.

Comment: Wicked. I'm currently look to cast the selected GeckoFX DOM to a JS friendly walkable DOM, and this method is a lot better then the navigation hack I've been using. I'll have to test this method out, thanks scott.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following:

```
WebBrowser.Navigate("javascript:void(document.getElementById('"+button.Id+"').click())");
```